# Find parent of specific child in the same table [SQL]

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have table look like this in phpmyadmin:

```
+-----------+-----------------+-------------------+
|nom_ele_id | nom_ele_title   | nom_ele_parent_id | 
+===========+=================+===================+
| 7060      | STANDARD        |   NULL            |  
| 6953      | SOL             |   7060            | 
| 6957      | type de sol     |   6953            |
+-----------+-----------------+-------------------+
```

I would like to have "nom_ele_tile" of parent with my "nom_ele_parent_id". 
I try this:

```
SELECT a.nom_ele_id, a.nom_ele_title, b.nom_ele_title AS 'nom_parent' 
FROM `immo_nomenclature_element` AS a 
LEFT JOIN `immo_nomenclature_element` AS b 
    on a.`nom_ele_parent_id` = b.`nom_ele_id`
```

but with this request i can't use WHERE `nom_ele_title`="type de sol" for exemple. and I get my entire table like this:

```
+-----------+-----------------+-------------------+
|nom_ele_id | nom_ele_title   | nom_parent        | 
+===========+=================+===================+
| 7060      | STANDARD        |   NULL            |  
| 6953      | SOL             |   STANDARD        | 
| 6957      | type de sol     |   SOL             |
+-----------+-----------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Please tag the database platform that you are using.

Comment: Yes! I use phpmyadmin

Comment: phpMyAdmin is not a database platform.

Comment: Ok.  I've added the MySQL tag for you.  phpmyadmin is a web client for MySQL, not the database platform itself.

Comment: `SELECT a.nom_ele_id, a.nom_ele_title,b.nom_ele_title   
FROM [immo_nomenclature_element] as a
left join [immo_nomenclature_element] as b on a.nom_ele_parent_id=b.nom_ele_id 
where a.nom_ele_title='type de sol'`

Comment: thank you for your precision. I won't make the mistake again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to add `where` clause:

```
SELECT a.nom_ele_id, a.nom_ele_title, b.nom_ele_title AS 'nom_parent' 
FROM `immo_nomenclature_element` AS a 
LEFT JOIN `immo_nomenclature_element` AS b 
    on a.`nom_ele_parent_id` = b.`nom_ele_id`
where a.nom_ele_title='type de sol'
```

Comment: It works perfectly thank you I had tried the problem was that I had forgotten the "a." before "nom_ele_title"....................

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get your question right.

You only want a nom_parent if the nom_ele_title="type de sol" , right?

Then you can just add a "and nom_ele_title="type de sol" to your join condition.

```
 SELECT    a.nom_ele_id,
          a.nom_ele_title,
          b.nom_ele_title             AS 'nom_parent'
FROM      `immo_nomenclature_element` AS a
LEFT JOIN `immo_nomenclature_element` AS b
ON        a.`nom_ele_parent_id` = b.`nom_ele_id and a.nom_ele_title="type de sol"
```

Comment: yes that's right! someone found the answer above.I tested your request and it returns the same thing as mine... I don't understand why